# Zero cart price Issue in M2 ADD TO CART rest API in case of new customers

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2

I'm working on M2 rest API's. I'm getting zero price issue in the same
API.

**How to re-create issue:**

```
1. Create new customer through rest API.
2. Login with the registered customer.
3. Now add the product to cart.
4. Now check the cart info through rest API URL.

Now cart showing zero price with zero total.

If you again add a new product or same product again. The correct price will be displayed.

The zero price issue always comes only in case of new customers. 

Request URL with parameters:
storeurl/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
SKU, qty, user_id
```

[image: First response to new customer]

[image: Second response to new customer]

Comment: have you enable rest api through admin or developer your own method?

Comment: Yes, The rest API working through my own method.

Comment: can you share your own method code?

Comment: Please check the URL:
http://mage2apis.bonafidenutrition.co.in/code.html

Comment: note this code Please send add to cart logic

Comment: Please check screenshot for addtocart logic:
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/641qk/3nb7
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/641qk/2y58